# Увеличение высоты title в UIButton

Tags: ios, button, height

Может и простой вопрос, но что-то не могу найти нужного ответа. 
У кнопки есть стандартный title. В некоторых случаях мне необходимо увеличить высоту этого title (НЕ ВЫСОТУ КНОПКИ, высота кнопки у меня большая). Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Задать высоту кнопки и увеличить шрифт.

Comment: @VAndrJ , не. Тут именно нужно увеличить высоты лейбла, без увеличения высоты текста и кнопки. Спасибо за отклик. Ответ уже нашел)

Answer (score 0):

button.titleLabel?.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: "Любая высота").isActive = true
Увеличивает высоту title кнопки, без увеличения высоты текста и высоты самой кнопки.